# Maxwell construction problem with FindRoot

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration, physics, chemistry

**A Maxwell construction is just an integral of area and then solving for a root to find vapor pressure.**

**This must be exactly the same value as where the Gibbs energy plot crosses at a point. I found that to be `p = 0.81`.**

**The problem is that my `areadifferential` function doesn't work properly; it doesn't return `p = 0.81`;**

**What mistake I have made in my coding?**

```
t = 0.95; 

p[v_] := (8*t)/(3*v - 1) - 3/v^2;

Plot[p[v], {v, 0.5, 3}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {0.6, 1}}, 
  AxesLabel -> {V/Vc, P/Pc}]

g[v_] := (-t)*Log[3*v - 1] + 0.95/(3*v - 1) - 9/(4*v); 

ParametricPlot[{p[v], g[v]}, {v, .65, 2.25},
  AxesLabel -> {P/Pc, G/NKT},
  PlotLabel -> "Gibbs Free Energy Vs. P/Pc"]
```

**That returns pressure `p = P/Pc = 0.81` as a plot which is correct**

[image]

**This is the error Maxwell construction "area differential" part**

```
pint[v_] := (8/3)*t*Log[3*v - 1] + 3/v;

areadifferential[p0_, v1guess_, v2guess_] := 
  (v1 = FindRoot[p[v] == p0, {v, v1guess}][[1,2]]; 
   v2 = FindRoot[p[v] == p0, {v, v2guess}][[1,2]];
pint[v2] - pint[v1] - p0*(v2 - v1))

FindRoot[areadifferential[p0, 0.7, 2] == 0, {p0, 0.8, 0.82}]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Good job on describing your problem.

Copying your definitions from your question

```
p[v_] := (8 t)/(3 v - 1) - 3/v^2
g[v_] := t/(3 v - 1) - t Log[-1 + 3 v] - 9/(4 v)
pint[v_] := 8/3 t Log[-1 + 3 v] + 3/v
t = 0.95
```

I found the value 0.81188 to be the value that minimized your `areadifferential` function (shown at the bottom).

Look at the plot of P/Pc vs V/Vc and note the three points corresponding to three different V/Vc values resulting in `p[v] = 0.8118`.

```
Module[
 {
  v1 = v /. FindRoot[p[v] == 0.8118, {v, 0.5}],
  p1,
  v2 = v /. FindRoot[p[v] == 0.8118, {v, 1}],
  p2,
  v3 = v /. FindRoot[p[v] == 0.8118, {v, 2}],
  p3
  },
 p1 = p[v1];
 p2 = p[v2];
 p3 = p[v3];
 Show[
  Plot[p[v], {v, 0.65, 2.25}, PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {0.6, 1}}, 
   AxesLabel -> {"V/Vc", "P/Pc"}],
  Graphics[
   {
    PointSize[0.03],
    Red,
    Point[{v1, p1}],
    Green,
    Point[{v2, p2}],
    Black,
    Point[{v3, p3}]
    }
   ]
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The problem that you are experiencing is because the value of 0.7 for `v1guess` is just to the right of the valley so it converges on the wrong point (i.e., the green point).

Change `v1guess` to 0.5 and you will be fine, it will converge on the red point. Using `v2guess` of 2.0 works fine causing convergence on the black point.

I slightly modified the `areadifferential` function to use `Module` rather than parenthesis. One needs to constrain the input arguments to be numeric so `FindRoot` doesn't complain (`FindFoot` first tries to work with symbolic arguments which doesn't work with your problem).

```
areadifferential[
p0_?NumericQ,
v1guess_?NumericQ,
v2guess_?NumericQ] := Module[
  {
   v1 = FindRoot[p[v] == p0, {v, v1guess}][[1, 2]],
   v2 = FindRoot[p[v] == p0, {v, v2guess}][[1, 2]]
   },
  pint[v2] - pint[v1] - p0*(v2 - v1)
  ]
```

and then

```
FindRoot[areadifferential[p0, 0.5, 2] == 0, {p0, 0.8, 0.82}]
(* {p0 -> 0.811879} *)
```